# How to detect an Arduino Yún / Yún shield IP address on a LAN

Tags: ssh, arduino

I'm writing code on a server to interact with an Arduino Yún shield via SSH. Is there a way for the server to detect the Yún shield LAN IP address automatically just like the IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this and found out that the Yún runs a Bonjour compatible daemon called [Avahi](http://linux.die.net/man/8/avahi-daemon) which sets a domain of arduino.local in your local network which makes the IDE aware of the board existence. I know because I have a Yún shield (not Yún) which by default gets assigned a different Bonjour name so the IDE can't recognize it.

So, if you need to access the Yún by name locally check the Avahi daemon configuration to see what name is used. If you need to access it from outside it's still possible by using a service like [noip](http://www.noip.com/) and opening the port on your router.

Please mark the answer as correct if this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible as your device may get an IP address from the ISP dynamically. Your device has to connect to your server and tell its IP address.

You can try something like, TCP/IP.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I just can't figure out how the arduino IDE is able to identify and obtain the IP for the Yun once it's connected to my LAN.   I'm just trying to achieve a similar purpose...